# Software to list contents of .wbcat files (Windows Backup Catalog Files)

Tags: windows, command-line, backup

The Windows Backup mechanism creates a lot of .zip files and some .wbcat files which describe the contents of the zip files. I could search (with the help of `unzip -l ... | grep -ri pattern`) where a certain file is. Using `xxd` I can already see some utf-16 path names in it.

Is there any software available to read the contents of the .wbcat files? I would prefer command line tools.